# How to pass Themes emotion.d.ts typings to Unit Tests with Emotion v11 + Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, styled-components, emotion

I'm migrating my typescript react project with Emotion from v10 to v11.
I've followed the documentation on https://emotion.sh/docs/typescript#define-a-theme
to define a 3rd lib theme. It works building and running the app. But does not work with my jest tests anymore. It says `theme` is empty.

This is how I'm wrapping my components.

```js
export const TestComponent: React.FC<Props> = ({ children }) => (
  <StylesProvider injectFirst>
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <StyledThemeProvider theme={theme}>
         {children}
      </StyledThemeProvider>
    </ThemeProvider>
  </StylesProvider>
);
```

````
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.20",
    "typescript": "4.1.3",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.1.4",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.0.0",
    "@testing-library/dom": "7.29.4",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.9",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.3",```
````